# How to show events in SharePoint Online home page

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, events

I just want to display FY, 19 Calendar Events in the SharePoint Online Modern page home page. Any Idea

Comment: @Dikesh, Group calendar is available as modern web part. It is very different from Event list web part.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Group Calendar** is available in Modern page web-part gallery. I sync the events from your outlook. Also, you can segregate these based on the O365 Groups/security groups. In one Homepage dashboard, people can refer the events which are related to their team!
Refer SS:

[image]

[image]